# Function existing

Tags: php, oop

Okay, i have little MVC what works like

somesite/classname/classfunction/function

```
class test(){
  public function test2(){
    // action will be 'function' in adress
    $action = $this->action ? $this->action : array($this, 'test3');
    function test3(){
      print 1;
    }
    $action();
  }
}
```

So, if we run `somesite/test/test2/test3` it will print '1', but if we run `somesite/test/test2/phpinfo` it will show phpinfo.
Question: how to check existing of function in class function ?

**UPD**
Don't forget about phpinfo, function_exists will show it.
method_exists search in class functions, but not in functions of class function
**UPD** Solution

```
class test{
    public function test2(){
    // site/test/test2/test3
        $tmpAction = $this->parenter->actions[1]; // test3  
        $test3 = function(){
            print 1;
        };
        if(isset($$tmpAction)){
            $$tmpAction();
        }else{
            $this->someDafaultFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Functions inside the class called `METHODS`. So, inside the class, simply - `if (method_exists($this, 'methodName'))`

Comment: That `test3` *inside* `test2` cannot be invoked using `array($this, 'test3')`. You should avoid functions within functions. Hoping it's just a bad copy-n-paste example.

Comment: @deceze avoid functions inside functions in general, or in php ?

Comment: @metal PHP obviously. In other languages functions within functions are a core design pattern. Note I also don't mean *anonymous* functions. I mean bare, global, conditional `function` declarations inside another function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php gives me defined functions. Nicely grouped to system and user. That's a way to weed `phpinfo` out. Still, I'd use `method_exists` and make `test3` a class method to make it clean OOP.

Comment: I don't need to use clean OOP. Question is about check existing function in class method.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/function-exists

http://php.net/method-exists

```
if ( function_exists('function_name') ) {
    // do something
}

if ( method_exists($obj, 'method_name') ) { /* */ }
```

You should also check out the magic method [__call()](http://php.net/language.oop5.overloading#object.call)

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a certain method in a class exists, use: [http://php.net/method-exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

```
   $c = new SomeClass();
   if (method_exists($c, "someMethod")) {
       $c->someMethod();
   }
```

You are also allowed to use the class name:

```
   if (method_exists("SomeClass", "someMethod")) {
       $c = new SomeClass();
       $c->someMethod();
   }
```

To "fix" your problem, make `test3()` a class method:

```
class test(){
  private function test3() {
      print 1;
  }
  public function test2(){
    // action will be 'function' in adress
    $action = $this->action ? $this->action : array($this, 'test3');

    if (method_exists($this, $action)) {
        $this->$action();
    } else {
        echo "Hey, you cannot call that!";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont need to use test3 as method of class, only as function of class method.

Comment: bcz if it will be a class method it will be as function and can be called from MVC structure like /test/test3

Comment: @Abyss Ah. I get it. Perhaps you should explain that in the question.

Comment: @Abyss: also if you declare it `private` ?

Comment: I was getting there as well, but my PHP install didn't have anonymous functions, so my testbed didn't work ;-). You could answer your own question if you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
class test{
    public function test2(){
    // site/test/test2/test3
        $tmpAction = $this->parenter->actions[1]; // test3  
        $test3 = function(){
            print 1;
        };
        if(isset($$tmpAction)){
            $$tmpAction();
        }else{
            $this->someDafaultFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that anonymous functions are supported from PHP 5.3.0.